# Who is filling the ELF header

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have ELF file which I dumped using readelf -h filename and I can see the different fields with the some values like entry point address is 0x99cc ,but really want to know from where these values get populated in fields.

Is it comes from some conf file or header file .I am talking specific to QNX ELF files How which way QNX chooses to fill this ELF header??

As I remember in Linux you can specify these values in kernel.conf file but not sure of QNX way

Comment: Look at http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html I think the loader fills the ELF header, but you can do it yourself, too.

Comment: Ya thats true but that information must be stored in some file and file I'm looking for.

Comment: Most of the values are calculated. And for the strings: check the `ld` source.

Comment: The ELF header contents are created by the linker, `ld(1)` (part of the binutils package in Linux). They are part of the executable/object/library file.